# Datastax cassandra driver giving wrong metadata information about host states

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I got a cluster with 2 DCs and each DC contain 2 nodes.

```
DC1:
192.168.60.81
192.168.60.82

DC2:
192.168.60.242
192.168.60.247
```

> Application is connected to 192.168.60.81 and hence the local DC for
> the application is DC1.

**Situation 1:**

Initially when all the nodes are up and when I try to get `cluster.metadata.allHosts`, it gives me information about the state of the host as UP.

**Situation 2:**

When any of the nodes in local datacenter (DC1) goes up or down, the `cluster.metadata.allHosts` gives me the correct host state information.

**Problem:**

When any of the nodes in remote datacenter (DC2) goes down, the `cluster.metadata.allHosts` gives me the host state information as DOWN correctly. But when the same node comes back up, still `cluster.metadata.allHosts` gives me the host state information as DOWN.

I registered with Host.StateListener to see if the events are fired for a node in remote DC. But unfortunately, when a node in remote DC comes back up it never notifies too.

Any help would be appreciated.

> Cassandra version in all nodes: 2.1.4
> Datastax java driver version: 2.1.9

Comment: Another problem that I am seeing with Host.StateListener is that the notification of host state in local DC is unordered. If a node comes back up again, the notification I am receiving are UP, DOWN and finally settles for UP again. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I got this answer from Andrew Tolbert from Datastax in the mail forum:**

> If the driver is not actively attempting to reconnect to DOWN nodes,
>   it is very dependent on Cassandra to deliver host UP events to the
>   driver.   My guess is that you must be using the default load
>   balancing policy or DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy with 0
>   usedRemoteHostsPerRemoteDC, so there is never an attempt to connect to
>   nodes in DC2.   Since you are running a fairly old version of C*, I
>   suspect upgrading might help.

**Explanation:**

The above answer makes perfect sense as my load balancing policy was DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy with 0 usedRemoteHostsPerRemoteDC. Hence the driver was not trying to reconnect to nodes in remote DC. Hence the state of the remote nodes were not consistent from driver's view.

> Thanks Andy.