# Cassandra ring status using CQL python driver

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-python-driver, datastax-python-driver

I am trying to get the health of the cassandra cluster, is there way to get that using the python CQL driver?

I was using pycassa earlier for the thrift based data model : https://github.com/datastax/python-driver

Is there a way to get cluster health or get_endpoints using the CQL python driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cluster is described by metadata as described in [official documentation](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/metadata.html).  For example, there is `Metadata.token_map` that [holds information](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/metadata.html#cassandra.metadata.TokenMap) about ring, tokens assignment, etc.

Comment: thanks @Alex, I am trying to find if there are any nodes down in the cluster by using the python driver. is there way to do it?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Python driver, but I can suggest to get all hosts with `Metadata.all_hosts()`, and check that `is_up` is set to `True`

Comment: Thanks @alex, but when I am trying it on the multi dc environment and I see the is_up value as None, any idea why the is_up shown as None?

https://pastebin.com/jj06StKQ

us-west-2 is the DC where I am connecting to and querying from. any thoughts?

Comment: `None` is shown when Cassandra doesn't know, is this host up or down.  I may recommend to try to open & close socket connection to that node if you get `None` instead of `True` or `False`

Comment: I also verified that the ports are open and nodetool status shows all nodes are up and running

Here is what I am doing, let me know if there is anything wrong here
https://pastebin.com/YrSi3BJy

Comment: Code looks correct for me. But please check with following SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34743472/datastax-cassandra-driver-giving-wrong-metadata-information-about-host-states & this documentation - https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/policies.html#cassandra.policies.DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy - you may not have connection to another DC configured, so cluster don't get status for nodes there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158635/discussion-between-user3435964-and-alex-ott).

Comment: I tried with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy and speicified multiple IP from local dc and remote dc, still no luck.. 
`>>> cluster = Cluster(['us-west-2_node', 'us-east-1_node'], auth_provider=auth_provider, load_balancing_policy=DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy(local_dc='us-west-2', used_hosts_per_remote_dc=0))`

Comment: Have you tried RoundRobinPolicy instead of DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy? That should give you the status of the nodes across all DCs.